# What's the difference between these two classes in TypeScript(with or without constructor)?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am following Angular's official document `The Tour of Heroes`. And I changed it a little. Now there are two different ways to write a class like below:

#### user.ts

```
export class User {
  url: string;
  id: number;
  username: string;
  email?: string;
  images: string[];
  files?: number[];
  password?: string;
  first_name?: string;
  last_name?: string;
}
```

This is the original way to write a class for verifying a `User`'s correctness and I also can create a new `User` like this:

`newUser: User = {url: '', id: 0, username: 'Alpha', images: []};`

---

I found a new way to write a class recently:

#### images.ts

```
export class Image {

  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public created: string,
    public userId: number,
    public fileUrl: string,
    public owner: string,
    public des?: string,
  ) { }

}
```

I can create a new `Image` like this:

`newImage = new Image(50, '20170822', 12,  '', 'Belter');`

I want to ask what's the difference between them and which one is better to use.

Comment: I think there is no 'right' way do describe classes.
I prefer the classic way to do it:

`export class Foo {
    private bar: string;

    constructor(bar: string) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}`

Comment: Why should we use `constructor`? It is simpler without it.

Comment: I didn't wrote that you(we) should, it's just as you prefer.

Comment: these are very different which makes a question too broad, make a one specific question

Comment: both of those examples seem better suited to an interface. I almost always use interfaces if i'm just trying to typecast an object, and don't implement any custom logic / methods.

Comment: The only reason I would say go for the first method over the second is for readability. Its much more obvious (to me at least) what the first example is doing, and will be easier to maintain down the line. Edit - just thought of a better reason why the first is superior. The constructor gives you less flexibility for optional parameters, if you have constructor (a: number, b: number, c?:number, d?:number)   and you can only provide a, b and d, you have to explicitly list c as 'undefined' .Unless you pass the whole thing as an object, but that's just becoming redundant

Comment: @diopside You answer is persuasive

Comment: @MaximKoretskyi Wow, you are an expert on Angular! Could you explain some more details about their differences? I am a true newbie about Angular and TypeScript.

Comment: @Belter, there's so much on the internet about the differences, you can ask a new **specific** question though about what you don't understand

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you do not actually instantiate the User class. You assign to your variable an object literal that conforms to the shape of the User class. Since Typescript has a structural type system this is allowed (the shape of the object matters not the declared type)

If you have a class that contains only data it would be better to define an interface and assign object literals to it. This is closer to the Javascript way of doing things. It would be better to declare it as an interface and not a class because the instanceof operator may give you unexpected results. For example in your first snippet `newUser instanceof User` will be false, because you assigned an object literal not an instance of the User class. The instanceof will give a compile time error with interfaces as they do not really exist in Javascript.

```
export interface User {
  url: string;
  id: number;
  username: string;
  email?: string;
  images: string[];
  files?: number[];
  password?: string;
  first_name?: string;
  last_name?: string;
}
var newUser: User = { url: '', id: 0, username: 'Alpha', images: [] };
```

Comment: Thanks, sometimes typescript's data types make me confused, so many class... ^_^

Comment: There is a bit of a shift in mindset you have to do if you come from a more traditional OOP language, but once you get used to it, the type system is your friend :)